# Passing an array to twig and displaying it

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an array in my controller. I pass this to my twig view along with another array one

```
 user_id = Array ( [0] => abc [1] => Def [2] => Hij )

 data =  [0] => HelpCenterBundle\Entity\New Object
    (
        [id:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\New:private] => 5
        [userId:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\New:private] => 314
        [comment:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\New:private] => 1
    )
```

I want to print it in a table.

```
    {% for countlist in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ countlist.id }}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td> here i want to print first element of user_count </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I tried with a for loop like

```
  {% for first in user_id %}
   <td>{{ first }}</td>
```

But it results in all the contents in a same line. Please help

Comment: Is not so clear what you want to achieve: only the first element of the `user_id` array?  try with `{{ user_id[0] }}` otherwise try to made an example of what is your goal

Answer (score 3):

seems you're trying to pass an array of objects to twig, which can still be done like so:

```
{% for key,value in array %}
    {% value.objectProperty %}
{% endfor %}
```

if you want the count of something you can do this:

```
{% value|length %}
```

it might also help for building html using arrays in twig to dump your values to see what you work with:

```
{{ dump(array) }}
```

this shows a nice pretty format of data that's passed to your template.